# How to do server-side processing using DataTAble in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, datatable

I am trying to implement server-side processing of my data table but I am struggling with it. I don't have much to post because I couldn't really do anything but I am going to post my JS for the data table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#dt-filter-select').DataTable({          
     "deferRender": true,          
     "order": [
        [2, "desc"]
      ],
     lengthChange: false
  });
});
```

And the HTML table:

```
<table id="dt-filter-select" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Admin</th>
        <th>Log text</th>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
          <?php foreach (get_all_log_history() as $logs) : ?>
             <tr>
          <td>
             <?php echo $logs["name"]; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $logs["log_text"]; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $logs["log_time"]; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
           <th>
           </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
 </table>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include a proper and detailed explanation of the actual issue. Just saying that you're "struggling" with something, for us, unknown isn't that helpful. Exactly where are you stuck? What happens when you run your code? What is it you want to "process" and when?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry Magnus but I really have nothing else to publish, I just don't know how to implement it at all.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here https://datatables.net/manual/data/ you shoud pass your data to the dataTable instance, instead of create a prefilled table  and let the plugin to fill data

something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#dt-filter-select').DataTable({          
     "deferRender": true,          
     "order": [
        [2, "desc"]
      ],
     lengthChange: false,
     data: <?php echo json_parse(echo get_all_log_history()) ?>
  });
});
```

Comment: this is a dynamic table, how am i suppose to print each row like this?

Comment: suppose you use just the client side, without php, you can fill your table rows passing data to the DataTable instance, and the table will show rows. If you use php to pass data to your html page you do the same thing, in the code above you pass server side data as json that will be processed client side by javascript